# Query many to many relationship in Linq and EFCore

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to do the following query in linq, however I'm getting an exception error, though my query looks fine to me. So here is the story:

**Diagram**

I have a many to many relationship between the users and the organizations. A user can be a part of many organizations, and an organization can have many users.

[image]

**What Im trying to query**

So given a user id, i want to query all the team members (users) i have in all the organizations i belong to. So

- Input: User X id (guid), and this user belongs to Organization A, and Organization B
- Output:

  User A, Organization A

  User B, Organization A

  User C, Organization B

**The Actual Query**

I though this would do just that

```
                var user = db.Users.Include(q => q.UserOrganization).SingleOrDefault( q => q.Id == id.ToString());
                var members = (from us in db.Users.Include(q => q.UserOrganization)
                                let orgs =  user.UserOrganization.Select(z => z.OrganizationId)
                                where us.UserOrganization.Any(q => orgs.Contains(q.OrganizationId) )
                                select new UserResource{
                                    id = Guid.Parse(us.Id),
                                    email = us.Email
                                }
                            ).ToArray();
```

My query fails on the where clause, with the error:

```
Processing of the LINQ expression 'AsQueryable<long>((Unhandled parameter: __Select_0))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core
```

Not sure what to change in the query. Please help.

PS: I wrote the query initially in MySql as follows:

```
SELECT UU.`Id`, UU.`Email`, UUO.`OrganizationId`
FROM aspnetusers AS UU
LEFT JOIN userorganization AS UUO ON UUO.`UserId` = `UU`.Id 
WHERE UUO.`OrganizationId` IN  
(
    SELECT UO.`OrganizationId` FROM aspnetusers AS U
    LEFT JOIN userorganization AS UO ON UO.UserId = U.Id 
    WHERE u.Id = '6caa67e7-69f3-49a3-ad61-10b07d379f10' 
)
AND UU.Id != '6caa67e7-69f3-49a3-ad61-10b07d379f10'
```

Comment: What ef version do you use? If 3.0, try 3.1 since 3.0 had issues with Contains in query.

Comment: its 3.0, im gonna split it as Holger suggested for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "SingleOrDefault" always executes the Query. User is not an IQueryable.

So the `let orgs =  user.UserOrganization.Select(z => z.OrganizationId)` cannot be translated to SQL, do your  `var orgs =  user.UserOrganization.Select(z => z.OrganizationId)` before the Query, in Plain C#. This cannot be used in SQL-Queries.

With orgs being an `IList<int>` it will work.

But it should be prefered to find a solution that can be solved with one query only. Here you have two.

The SingleOrDefault might be not useful, you go better without, than you have a simple IQueryable. And The "Any" can most often be realized with a simple (Inner) Join, returning only values, if you have a match between to tables. That is the Same as Where - Any - Contains